# Passing a pointer to a function - dereference or send directly?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function in this way:

```
void foo(structTemp* p)
{
  .
  p->field1 = 1;
  p->field2 = 2;
  .
  foo_2(?????);
}

void foo_2(structTemp* p, int c)
{
   Need to use the pointer 'p' from foo here in this function.
}
```

I used foo_2(p, 3) but it shows errors. How do I correctly pass the pointer p to be used in foo_2 ?

EDIT:
I have tried to call the function as foo_2(p, 2) or foo_2(**p, 2)  but getting errors. Can you please help?

Comment: It says Declaration is compatible with previously declared prototype.

Comment: write  `void foo_2(structTemp* p, int c);` above `foo`.

Comment: I have defined the protoype at the top of the file. Still I am having problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you tried to call it *is* correct but you probably have the problem that `foo2` is not declared before you try to use it - in that case it would complain about the declaration not matching an earlier (default) one.

You can check/fix this either by changing the order of the two functions or providing a declaration (prototype) before `foo`, so that the default prototype is not used:

```
void foo_2 (structTemp*, int);
```

So either of:

```
void foo_2 (structTemp* p, int c) {
    // Weave your magic here
}

void foo (structTemp* p) {
   foo_2 (p, 3);
}
```

or:

```
void foo_2 (structTemp*, int);

void foo (structTemp* p) {
   foo_2 (p, 3);
}

void foo_2 (structTemp* p, int c) {
    // Weave your magic here
}
```

would work fine since they both involve declaring `foo_2` as you need it before the first use.

If you *do* already have a prototype, you should check it. Since your comment contains text indicating the compiler is complaining about an incompatible declaration, an existing prototype would have to be incorrect.

Comment: I have defined the prototype at the top of the file itself.

    line 786: Error:  #159: declaration is incompatible with previous foo_2(declared at line 587)   void foo_2(structTemp* p, int c)

Also, should I call foo_2 as foo_2(*p, 3) or foo_2(p, 3) ?

Comment: Well, @mane, if you're getting `declaration is incompatible with previous ...`, then either you _haven't_ done so, or you've done so _incorrectly._ Based on your definitions, you should use the latter (a naked `p` without dereferencing).

Comment: Thanks fellas. There was a spelling mistake in the prototype and I was calling the function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To use `p` inside `foo_2`, you do exactly the same as in foo.

`p->field1` is the same as `(*p).field1`  wich means: The variable field1 inside the struct pointed by p.

So, something like this:

```
void foo(structTemp* p)
{
  .
  p->field1 = 1;
  p->field2 = 2;
  .
  foo_2(p,3);

  printf("field1 %d\nfield2 %d",p->field1, p->field2); 

}

void foo_2(structTemp* p, int c)
{
   p->field2 = 3;
}
```

Would print:

```
field1 1
field2 3
```

Assuming your struct is something like:

```
typedef struct _t{

  int field1, field2;

}structTemp;
```

If you have problems with this, is probably because of some error in your variable declarations/names.

Comment: Thank you. It is solved now and the problem was a silly spelling mistake! Sorry for the bother.

Comment: No problem. 

If you finished  this question, close the thread.